# program that will send a magic packet to a certian ip

Tags: c++, python, c, router

I need to code a C, C++, .bat, or Python program. It should detect if there is a person trying to connect to a certain IP address(192.168.1.149) through a certain port(25570) from outside the router/ fire wall. The program will then send a magic packet to an IP address (192.168.1.149). The magic packet will then wake up the computer. because the computer will be in sleep mode the code will probably have to be on another computer in the network(I don't want this). Maybe even in the router or DNS. I have a windows 7 computer. It is the computer supposed to be in sleep mode. I need people who answer this question to give me a guide **I am not a really good coder so this is why I am asking this question**

here is my router info:
https://www.asus.com/Networking/RTN65U/
Sorry I have a really old DNS so I cant give you the specs.
How would I do this?
thx.

Comment: Have you attempted to come up with a solution on your own yet? If so, can you show us what your thought process is so we can guide you?

Comment: I figured out how to do this with python:                      import socket                                                       
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)                
s.sendto('\xff'*6 + '\x00\x02\xb3\x07\xb6\xd1'*16,                  ('192.168.1.255', 80))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some Python code I use on one of my network machines to wake up another. Not sure where I got it originally, but it works great. Hopefully you can adapt it for your purposes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
s.sendto('\xff'*6+'\x00\x11\x22\x33\x44\x55'*16, ('192.168.0.255', 9))
print "Attempted to wake host"
```

Note that the `\x00\x11` etc. stuff is the MAC address of the machine to be awakened and should be replaced with your machine's MAC address (converted to hex bytes). The `192.168.0.255` is the broadcast address of the network and, again, should be replaced with yours.